# How to find limit of the sequence $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +kn}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I find the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +kn}} \quad?$$

I have tried to solve it using squeeze theorem:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +kn}} > \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +n^2}} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {2n^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}} $$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +kn}} <\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2}} = 1.$$

But I could not find the sequences with the same limits.

Please help - how to solve this?

Comment: this is just a riemann sum integral 0 to 1 of 1/sqrt.1+x

Comment: Something is wrong here. How are you summing from $n$ to $n$?

Comment: @Rustyn:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}_{n\text{ times}}=1$$

Comment: @K.Ghosh This comment worth for an answer. Why don't you post it as an answer.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thx. I was confused by indexing variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

$$\int _a^b {f(x) dx}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b-a}{n}\sum \limits_{k=1}^n f\left(a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}\right)  \tag 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +kn}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {1 +k\frac{1}{n}}} \tag 2$$

Can you proceed after that?

Comment: And when you get the result, you may indeed verify that it satisfies the inequalities you derived.

Comment: can you plz. solve it ...

Comment: @ram : you just need to find $f(x)$ and integral limits $a,b$. Then evaluate the integral. One more hint that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Can you find the result now?

Comment: Thanks Sir !!! I have the answer $2\sqrt {2} - 2$.

Comment: @ram  That's right. You got it.

Comment: @Mathlover shouldnot $f(x)$ be $\frac{1}{\sqrt\(1+x\)}$

Comment: @jim  it can be selected such. if you select $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ you must use $a=0$ and $b=1$. In my case,  $a=1$ , $b=2$

Comment: @Mathlover may you please derive how for a=0 we get the f(x) =1/√x form ? And for a=1 we get f(x) =1/√x+1 ? I always gets confused with this

Answer (score 1):

In comments to this [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3370438/how-to-solve-lim-n-to-infty-left-sum-k-1n-frac1-sqrtn2k-rig/3370503#3370503), this problem was mentioned and, being concerned by asymptotics, I tried to use a similar approach.
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt {n^2 +kn}}=\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},n+1\right)-\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2},2
   n+1\right)}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{H_{2 n}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-H_n^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{n}}$$ where appear the Hurwitz zeta function and  generalized harmonic numbers.
Using the asymptotics
$$H_{p}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=2 \sqrt{p}+\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac 1 {2\sqrt p}-\frac 1{24p\sqrt p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^{7/2}}\right)$$ Apply it twice and continue with Taylor series to get
$$S_n=(2 \sqrt{2}-2) \left(1-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2} n}+\frac{2+3 \sqrt{2}}{192 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right) \right)$$
For the fun of it, let us compute using $n=10^k$ to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0 & 0.70891579073141078638 & 0.70710678118654752440 \\
 1 & 0.81405181655943694309 & 0.81405158010700953614 \\
 2 & 0.82696535217966202992 & 0.82696535215592309803 \\
 3 & 0.82828070507205876331 & 0.82828070507205638932 \\
 4 & 0.82841248035460217890 & 0.82841248035460217866 \\
 5 & 0.82842566028278955788 & 0.82842566028278955788 \\
 6 & 0.82842697829960762615 & 0.82842697829960762615
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Very nice answer!