# A limit of a sequence when squeeze doesn't work

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{{1}\over{\sqrt{n^2+2kn}}}$$

How should one approach such a question? A hint would be helpful

Comment: Check the question , It is very similiar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266322/how-to-find-limit-of-the-sequence-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrt-n2-kn/266325#comment581562_266325

Comment: Squeeze DOES work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: rewrite this as a Riemann sum, so that the limit is an integral.

Answer (score 2):

I try
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{{1}\over{\sqrt{n^2+2kn}}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{{1}\over{\sqrt{1+\frac{2k}{n}}}}\\
&=\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}\,\,dx\end{align}